# Using Invoke-SqlCmd to Query and export to Text File. But the data has been Truncated Follow By 3 Dots

Tags: powershell, truncated

I'm trying to use Invoke-SqlCmd to query data and save to text file.
Anyhow i found that some of the records has been truncated and added 3 dots at the back.

```
$SQLInstanceName = "Server01"
$DBName = "ABC"
$TextFile = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$SQLQuery = "SELECT [Description] FROM [dbo].[TestTable]" 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstanceName -Query $SQLQuery -Database $DBName | Out-File -filePath $TextFile
```

It is lesser than 400 characters per records.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The records in [description] column of [TestTable] table might have multiple lines in it. That's why you are getting dots. Try using the below script.

```
$SQLInstanceName = "Server01"
$DBName = "ABC"
$TextFile = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$SQLQuery = "SELECT [Description] FROM [dbo].[TestTable]" 

$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstanceName -Query $SQLQuery -Database $DBName 

"Description`r`n-----------`r`n" | Out-File -filePath $TextFile # Creates a new file with Header

Foreach($Result in $Results)
{
    "$($Result.Description)`r`n"  | Out-File -filePath $TextFile -Append
}
```

Comment: Hi Akhiesh,
I follow your coding, but the result still same. The result still truncated.
I found that truncated in Invoke-Sqlcmd.

Comment: Did you tried to print the content of $Result.Description in powershell?

Comment: Can you please provide the datatype of [Description] column?